# c printing address of an array pointed to by a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, memory-address

In the code below, `str` is a pointer that stores the address of the array `Goodbye`. The address of array `Goodbye` starts at `4196004` and the value of pointer `*str2` is `-1226226648`. My question is, is there a way to print address of array `Goodbye` using the pointer `*str2`?

I tried this line `printf("%d %d %s\n", *str2, str2, str2);` that dereferences `str2` and it prints `71` which is ascii for `H`, but how would I print the address `4196004`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

char str1[] = "Hello";
char *str2 = "Goodbye";

printf("%d %d %s\n", &str1, str1, str1);
printf("%p %d %s\n", &str2, str2, str2);

}

Output: 
-1226226640 -1226226640 Hello
-1226226648 4196004 Goodbye
```

Comment: You have undefined behaviours. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5286451/4389800

Comment: @artic sol  In your code snippet there is no name str.:)

Answer (score 1):

Your code invokes Undefined Behavior, since you try to print addresses without using `%p`

[`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) mentions:

> `p`    Pointer address

and don't cast to `void`, as you ought to.

So, do it like this instead:

```
printf("%p %p %s\n", (void*)&str1, (void*)str1, str1);
printf("%p %p %s\n", (void*)&str2, (void*)str2, str2);
```

Possible output:

```
0x7ffddaf7e67a 0x7ffddaf7e67a Hello
0x7ffddaf7e670 0x4005c4 Goodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

Concerning `str2` we can distinguish "the address to which pointer `str2` points to", which is the address where string literal `Goodbye` will reside (e.g. `0x10007bf04`) from "the address at which pointer `str2` is stored", which is the address of the variable (e.g. `0x7fff5fbff710`) in which the address value `0x10007bf04` is stored.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char str1[] = "Hello";
    char *str2 = "Goodbye";

    printf("%p %p %s\n", (void*)&str1[0], (void*)str1, str1);
    printf("%p %p %s\n", (void*)&str2, (void*)str2, str2);

}
```

In contrast to pointers, `*str2` denotes a character value as it dereferences pointer `str2`. Getting the "address of *str2" would then be the address of the first character of the string literal to which `str2` points to. You could write this as `&(*str2)` or `&str2[0]`, but both translate to `str2`.

Note that printing a pointer using format `"%d"` invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Start by fixing undefined behavior - cast your pointers to `void*`, and use `%p` to print them:

```
printf("%p %p %s\n", (void*)&str1, (void*)str1, str1);
printf("%p %p %s\n", (void*)&str2, (void*)str2, str2);
```

This [produces the following output](https://ideone.com/1v6d14):

```
0x7ffe95676bf0 0x7ffe95676bf0 Hello
0x7ffe95676be8 0x2b4dca5eb7d4 Goodbye
```

Let's go through it to see why there is a difference between printing lines for `str1` and `str2`.

The reason is that `str1` is an array, while `str2` is a pointer. When you take a pointer to an array with operator `&` you produce a pointer to array's initial element; when you convert an array to a pointer implicitly, you also get a pointer to array's initial element. Therefore, both printouts of `%p` for `&str1` and `str1` produce the same value of `0x7ffe95676bf0`.

On the other hand, `str2` is a pointer. It points to something (the string literal `"Goodbye"`), but it also has an address of its own. When you print `str2` without `&`, you get the value of the pointer, i.e. the location of string literal `"Goodbye"`. When you print `&str2`, however, you get a pointer to pointer `str2`, which is the location of `str2`. This is different from the location of `"Goodbye"`, so the printout is different.

If you start with the address of `str2`, i.e.

```
char *str2 = "Goodbye";
char **ptrStr2 = &str2;
```

you can get the location of `"Goodbye"` by dereferencing, i.e.

```
printf("%p %s\n", (void*)*ptrStr2, *ptrStr2);
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/xqodzo)

Comment: thanks very much for your helpful reply. Could I ask one further question please? Is it required to cast to `void*` if you use `%p` and if so - why is this necessary?

Comment: @articsol Yes, it is required for all pointers other than char and unsigned char pointers, which are guaranteed to have the same representation as void pointers. %p assumes that you pass a void pointer, so you need to add a cast to ensure passing correct representation.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you shall use correct conversion specifiers in the function `printf`. Otherwise the behavior of the function is undefined.

So these calls

```
printf("%d %d %s\n", &str1, str1, str1);
printf("%p %d %s\n", &str2, str2, str2);
```

are wrong because there is used the conversion specifier `%d` with pointers.

> My question is, is there a way to print address of array Goodbye using
>   the pointer *str2?

In fact the address of the array that corresponds to the string literal `"Goodbye"` is the same as the address of the first character of the string literal.

```
char *str2 = "Goodbye";
```

However you can not obtain a pointer to the string literal using the pointer `str2`.

What is the problem?

The pointer `str2` knows nothing about whether it points to a single object of the type `char` or to the first character of some array. It does not keep such an information.

Take into account that the array that corresponds to the string literal `"Goodbye"` has type `char[8]`. So a pointer that would point to the array shall have type `char ( * )[8]`.

You could write for example

```
char ( *str2 )[8] = &"Goodbye";
```

In this case the pointer `str2` indeed will have the address of the array. Otherwise having the pointer as it is defined in your example

```
char *str2 = "Goodbye";
```

you can not get the address of the array because as it was mentioned the pointer knows nothing about the array and its size.

On the other hand the value of the address of the first character of the string literal is equal to the value of a pointer to the string literal. That is if to consider the first declaration

```
char str1[] = "Hello";
```

then the expressions `str1` and `&str1` will yield the same value though the expressions have different types. The first one has the type `char *` (if the expression is used in a context when an array designator is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element). And the second one has the type `char ( * )[6]`.  But the both values will be equal.:)

It is seem from the output (provided that you used correct conversion specifiers)

```
-1226226640 -1226226640 Hello
```