# how to pass one pointer value to another pointer?like can I do int *a=*b;where b is defined already but the pointer a is not addressing to any integer

Tags: c, pointers

Actually I was reading about pointers and wanted to try something ,so I wrote a small code

```
int main(){
    int x = 10;
   int *ptr;
    ptr = &x;                   
    printf("%d is stored at address %d\n",x,ptr );
    int *c=*ptr;
    c=&ptr;
   printf("location is %d\n",c);
 printf("value of c= %d",*c);
}
```

the result I expected was value  of c would be 10  but instead the value came as the location of x.
output: `10 is stored at address 997523644 location is 997523648 value of c= 997523644`

does this problem arise because I didnt pass any location as first?or is it something else or my question is quite silly I know:D,Can anyone help me?

Comment: `int *c = *ptr` is equivalent to `int *c = 10`, but the initialization is irrelevant since you overwrite the value of `c` in the next line.  `int **d = &ptr` would be a valid initialization of a pointer to pointer to int, but `c = &ptr` is attempting to store an `int **` in an `int *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int* c = ptr` should be enough, you can read it as: c is pointer to integer, `c = ptr` since `ptr` is already a pointer this will make both c and ptr point to the same value.

What you are currently doing: `c=&ptr;` is making c point to the address of ptr, so if you want to access x value you will need to dereference twice, once to get the address of ptr, and once again to get the content of x.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that is missing in the code that you have provided, is the declaration of `ptr`. You haven't declared the `ptr` variable yet, so first you need to do

```
int *ptr;
```

, which tells that you need a pointer variable to point to a `int` variable.

Since you declare another pointer `int *c` and `ptr` is already a pointer, you only need to assign `int *c = ptr` (or `c=ptr` in case you want to declare `int *c` seperately first), which will store the value of `ptr` (location of `x`) to `c`. So, doing `int *c=*ptr` is wrong. Now you can access the value of `x` by doing **derefencing** (`*c` or `*ptr`), which you already did.

Doing `c=&ptr` is also wrong, because `c` is of type `int *` and `&ptr` is of type `int **`. In case you are trying to store the address of `ptr`, you have to first declare a variable of type `int **`, for example `int **d`. Now `d=&ptr` is valid and `d` holds a value which is the address of `ptr`. **Dereferencing** `d` (`*d`) should give you the value that the address of `ptr` is holding, which is nothing but the address of `x` (same as the value of `c`). If you **dereference** `d` twice (`**d`), you should get the back the value of `x` (`10`).

Answer (score 0):

Changed it to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 10;
    int *ptr = &x;                   
    printf("%d is stored at address %p\n",x,ptr );
    int *c=ptr;
    int d = &ptr;
    printf("location is %p\n", c);
    printf("value of c= %d", *c);
    return 0;
}
```

As **ptr** is an address already, you can just do it:

```
int *c=ptr;
```

Output is:

```
10 is stored at address 0x7ffd6127dd54
location is 0x7ffd6127dd54
value of c= 10
```

To print variable address, you can check this answer:
[Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5286458/2952011)

Comment: what is the use of "d" here sir?

Comment: You wanted to keep the address of ptr in your code. I kept this in d. @pratikneupane

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the line

```
c=&ptr;
```

The above line means that you're setting C as the location of ptr, which is some random value. So C points to the location of ptr, and ptr points to the location of x. C is a double-pointer

Alternatively, if you keep that line in there, you can make it work by instead printing

```
printf("value of c= %d",**c);
```

either solution would get the output you expect